# Why does my file being downloaded have my page's HTML appended?

Tags: php

#### Update:

Never mind. It was happening because it was adding the headers back. So I moved the php code separate from html and it worked. thanks guys

I am using the code below

```
 <?php 
    
        $target_path = "Files/";
        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['decryptfile']['name']);
            
                        
                    $fp = fopen('Files/'.$_FILES['file']['name'], 'rb');
            header('Content-type: '.$_FILES['file']["type"]);                                                              
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_FILES['file']['name'].'"'); 
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize('decryptedFiles/'.$_FILES['file']['name']));
    
            
            fpassthru($fp);
            exit;
            die();
                
        
        
        
        
    ?>
    
    
    
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    Choose a file : <input name="file" type="file" /><br /><p>
    Start  process</a></center></p>
    <p><center><input type="submit" value="File" /></center></p>
    
    </form>
```

My file contents are:

1234567890

when I download the file it shows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

</head>
  
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    Choose a file : <input name="file" type="file" /><br /><p>
    Start  process</a></center></p>
    <p><center><input type="submit" value="File" /></center></p>
    
    </form>
   

1234567890
```

Problem is that it appends (includes) the html of my web page to the file... how can I avoid that. thanks

Comment: You tagged both `[php4]` and `[php5]`. Which one is it?

Comment: @alex none of them. it's inapplicable to version, added just out of general ignorance. BTW, php5 tag shouldn't be existed at all. Should be an alias to php. as for printed HTML - I hope you can see it now. It was quite obvious

Comment: If you've exited, you're already dead :) Anyway, are you sure this HTML is not in the actual file to be downloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `exit` after `fpassthru()`.

Also, you should look at the cleaner [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

Answer (score 1):

If there's any content following the above code, you need to [`die()`](http://php.net/die), or it will still be output as normal.

Comment: what do u mean...can you be more specific?

Comment: @user You need to call `die()` to stop the script after the above code.

Comment: i did use exit. still doesnt matter with die either

Comment: @user Then give us more information. What do you mean by "appends the HTML of my web page"? Where is that coming from? How's the above code called? Is there any other code following it?

Comment: You chose `die()` over `exit`? Glass half empty? :P

Comment: @alex I just like to be able to say "you need to die." ;p